# Generating Numerical Categorial Variables based on String Categorial Variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variables

I am trying to generate a numeric categorial variables (similar to ID) for a list of strings.

In detail, each 'Artist' should be assigned an ID.

[image]

Comment: Your question needs more detail and explanation, else I'm afraid it will be closed. Furthermore you shouldn't paste your data/code as a picture, provide it in a text format so people can copy it and try to reproduce your problem themself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can try:

```
# create a mapping for artist to a number
maps = {ar:en for en, ar in enumerate(df['artist'].unique())}
df['artist_code'] = df['artist'].map(maps)

  artist  artist_code
0      a            0
1      a            0
2      a            0
3      b            1
4      c            2
```

> **Sample Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'artist':['a','a','a','b','c']})
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,use [`Series.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html)

```
df['artist_code']=df['artis'].factorize()[0]
```

or [`groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html)

```
df['artist_code'] = df.groupby('artist').ngroup()

#  artist  artist_code
#0      a            0
#1      a            0
#2      a            0
#3      b            1
#4      c            2
```